# Inlining external code - copyright?

Tags: discussion, edits, code, licensing

Today I came about a question in the review queue which could benefit from inlining the small code sample that was linked by OP by including it directly into the question.

But: Code hosted on Stack Overflow is licensed as [CC by-sa](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). So my question is:

- Can I simply assume the code OP linked to is available for re-licensing under that license?
- Or can we assume that code snippets are not sufficiently original to warrant copyright protection (according to US? law?)?
- Or do we always need to get the OP's permission first?

Comment: If the post relies on external content, close it if a question and flag it if an answer. Don't forget to downvote.

Comment: If you are unsure, ask the op do it. and downvote if the question is unclear without it.

Comment: "could benefit from" or the question requires that code for an MCVE? if it's the latter then it should be closed and let the OP decide if they want to edit it in to have it re-opened.

Comment: IANAL (1) No. (2) Not in general. Fair use is not clearly-defined in many relevant cases. You may be able to assess *some* very clear cases, but don't be overconfident, and verify that all participants are under US jurisdiction. (3) Getting the OP's permission (with implication that they have rights) is the only way to do this without any potential legal liability.